# Repeated styles not overwriting original styles in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a site that works in IE9 / Chrome / FF / Safari just fine, but when viewed in IE8 has a whole slew of issues. To help fix this I have been adding conditional css for (IE8 only) in the header under a style element to fix the issues (I know this isn't the correct way to do this). My plan was to wrap everything up into a new stylesheet after I am done.

I added the style element near the end of the header and after any other stylesheets so there shouldn't be any other styles overwriting the new css. This is about the 10th element that I am trying to change and this technique has worked up until this point, but now I have gotten to an element that wont take the new styles.

I can alter the original stylesheet to achieve the desired results, but for some reason the added CSS in the header has no effect on these elements.

I have tried disabling other other stylesheets from loading with no effect.

I disabled my caching plugin.

I am really at wits end here and any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

For reference I am trying to change the width of the both the .text and .image elements, and also change the h2 font-size and line-height.

Site can be found here http://fertileweb.com/demosite

HTML

```
<div class="infoBox">
<div id="rfid" class="info">
<div class="image">
<img class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" width="477" height="589" alt="RFID_image" src="http://localhost/orh/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/RFID_image1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="text">
<div class="top">
<img alt="" src="http://localhost/orh/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/RFID_section.png">
<h2>RFID Tagging of Sperm, Eggs and Embryos</h2>
</div>
<p>
ORH is the first clinic in the USA and the only one in Washington state to use radio frequency ID tagging to track your eggs, sperm and embryos for all fertility treatments - Inseminations (IUIs), and IVF or ICSI procedures, Donor Egg or Donor Sperm.
<a href=""></a>
<span>......because your Peace of Mind matters</span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Original CSS

```
 .infoBox { width: 99.5%; float: left; padding-top: 10px; }
.infoBox .info { width: 98.5%; float: left; margin-top: 50px; border-left: 3px solid #459b45; }
.infoBox .image { float: right; max-width: 480px; }
.infoBox .text { float: none; max-width: 605px; padding-left: 23px; }
.infoBox .top { width: 100%; min-height: 250px; }
.infoBox .top img { float:left; padding: 10px 10px 0 0; }
.infoBox h2 { color: #090405; font-size: 46px; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; font-weight: 200; line-height: 54px; }
.infoBox p { color: #3d3d3d; font-size: 17px; max-width: 600px; line-height: 33px; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; padding-left: 85px; }
```

Some of the different derivations I have tried so far to change the width of the .text element.

```
.infoBox .text { max-width:500px;}
.infoBox .info .text {max-width:500px;}
.infoBox #rfid .text {max-width:500px;}
.infoBox .info .text .top {max-width:500px;}
.infoBox #rfid .text .top {max-width:500px;}
.contantcntr .infoBox .text { max-width:500px;}
.contantcntr .infoBox .info .text {max-width:500px;}
.contantcntr .infoBox #rfid .text {max-width:500px;}
.contantcntr .infoBox .info .text .top {max-width:500px;}
.contantcntr .infoBox #rfid .text .top {max-width:500px;}
.infoBox .text { width:500px;}
.infoBox .info .text {width:500px;}
.infoBox #rfid .text {width:500px;}
.infoBox .info .text .top {width:500px;}
.infoBox #rfid .text .top {width:500px;}
.contantcntr .infoBox .text {width:500px;}
.contantcntr .infoBox .info .text {width:500px;}
.contantcntr .infoBox #rfid .text {width:500px;}
.contantcntr .infoBox .info .text .top {width:500px;}
.contantcntr .infoBox #rfid .text .top {width:500px;}
.infoBox .text { float: none; max-width: 500px; padding-left: 23px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to validate your [HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffertileweb.com%2Fdemosite%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) and [CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffertileweb.com%2Fdemosite%2F&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en) code and it failed. This should be the first step of debugging.

Here's your IE8-only style element:

```
<!-- IE8 css fixes -->
<style>
.infoBox .text { float: none; max-width: 605px; padding-left: 23px; }

<!--[if IE 8]>

/* many CSS rules */

</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Your conditional comment should wrap the `style` element. Here your opening CC is *inside* the element. AFAIK it doesn't work.

Then, unrelated to IE8 probably, [style.css](http://fertileweb.com/demosite/wp-content/themes/aron/style.css) lacks a slash at the very beginning of the stylesheet:

```
*
 comment
*/

(...)
```

Comment: I was actively changing things on the demosite. I have been testing  for IE8 with browserstack.com and this is the best way I know how. I normally do all my work locally. The conditional comment no longer wraps the style element, I was merely trying to test bringing both styles directly onto the header to test cascading.

Comment: And you are correct about the conditional statement should wrap the element, and not open inside the element. I was just trying a few different things.

Comment: Thanks for the / find on the style sheet. I looked through the validations for both and don't see anything useful. The CSS errors were on unrelated material and the HTML errors seem to be based on the validator getting confused with some PHP intersperced within the HTML.

Comment: Please don't give an URL if you're still modifying code in it... Are there still problems in IE8? I think I desactivated JS in mine so no fixed menu when scrolling, a caption too close to an image and fonts very different (bold, etc) but otherwise seems correct enough.